# Elasticsearch : How to get all indices that ever existed

Tags: elasticsearch

is there a way to find out the names of all the indices ever created? Even after the index might have been deleted. Does elastic store such historical info?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a plugin that keeps an audit trail for all changes that happened in your ES cluster might do the trick.

If you use the [changes plugin](https://github.com/derryx/elasticsearch-changes-plugin) (or a [more recent one](https://github.com/salyh/elasticsearch-sample-plugin-audit)), then you can query it for all the changes in all indices using

```
curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/_changes
```

and your response will contain all the index names that were at least created. Not sure this plugin works with the latest versions of ES, though.